# Creating a service like app and reacting to notifications and system wide events

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7

is there a way to create a service like application on windows phone 7.5 so that this application will stay active and will be able to receive raw notification without the user intervention even if it isn't he foreground application?

What i'm trying to do is to create an application that sits quietly in the background and waits for a notification from a website , and when receiving it, send back some info, and then sits there silently again.

By this I'm trying to solve an annoying every day situation, for which I couldn't find an app , so I'm sorry for not describing the whole situation :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK it is not possible in WP7 to exactly like you want. Like you wrote - Background Agent runs only every 30min and when your app goes into background, it gets killed.

So you have to stay with 30min limit - or change the phone platform.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the original "Push Notification Services" to send update to a device from a website.

[Push Notifications for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff402537%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

These can even be used to Launch or deep link into your application from the notification of the user taps on the Notification popup or Toast message.

Although you could use background agents to poll a site for updates it would be more efficient for the server to send the update to the phone when it's available.

Only limitation is that you app has to be run at least once to negotiate with your server and record the required Microsoft Push notification authentication and detail (notificationUri)

There is also a Cloud based pack available to make use of the service as well.

[Video Walkthrough of Push notification services using Azure](http://push%20notifications%20for%20Windows%20Phone%20development)

Answer (score -2):

What you want to do , can easily be done with [Background Agents for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=vs.92%29.aspx)

Comment: from what I know about  Background Agents is that thy run every 30 minus so the best way I can model my situation with  Background Agents is to create a PeriodicTask which will be called every 30 minutes and in that task query my website for the current status and anything to do. Although this is doable I'm still looking to find a solution in order to be able to listen for raw notification even if the application is dormant , so it can respond at any time not just at 30 min intervals

Comment: Not possible. Background Agents is the only possible way to handle background tasks.